# How to run a python script with sudo without being prompted for a password

Tags: python, password

I have a python script that restarts the mouse driver

```
import os

os.system("sudo modprobe -r psmouse")
os.system("sudo modprobe psmouse")
```

since my mouse doesn't always show up on start. What is a way I can run it on start up without being prompted for a password?

Comment: Use subprocess.Popen() or -call. os.system is terribly outdated, deprecated and old fashioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your sudoers file so that a given user can execute a specific script without a password request.

Example:

```
someusername    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /some/path/to/script/somescript
```

Similar Post / Reference: [How do I sudo a command in a script without being asked for a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password)

Comment: If it's a dupe, please mark it as such, instead of re- answering.

Comment: It is not a dupe of the question you linked.  The person asking a question simply asked it wrong.  OP should have asked, "how do I load a kernel module on boot?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reload the mouse drive on start up, it may be more convenient to include the commands in `/etc/rc.local`. rc.local runs as root, so you don't need any sudo commands. By default it just contains comments and and exit 0 command. Assuming that you have the default rc.local, edit it to look (something like) like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> OP should have asked, "how do I load a kernel module on boot?"

Edit the `/etc/modules` file and add the name of the module (without the `.ko` extension) on its own line. On boot the kernel will try to load all the modules named in this file.

Source: [How to install 3rd party module so that it is loaded on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299676/how-to-install-3rd-party-module-so-that-it-is-loaded-on-boot)