# Low Wi-Fi signal in HP laptop with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

I am new Ubuntu user. I have problem with low signal in my laptop. I searched for ways to fix the problem. I found the best solution by using commands below:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

The question is:

1. What does it mean?
2. The signal is very strong after I run those command, but I have to run the command every time I run my laptop. Is there any solution to make it permanent?

Comment: rtl8723be is a module, to load this on boot, read through this and follow the instructions,  https://askubuntu.com/questions/299676/how-to-install-3rd-party-module-so-that-it-is-loaded-on-boot

Answer (score 3):

The driver *rtl8723be* that is included in Ubuntu 16.04 is not yet able to autoselect which antenna wire has the best signal strength.

[image]

It is therefor necessary to do some trial and error to determine if the best antenna is #1 or #2. You have determined that, in your case, it is #1.

We can create a file that will instruct the system to load the driver with the correct parameter automagically on boot. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.