# What is Generic* disabled

Tags: networking, network-manager

While using wifi as hotspot,it worked well for few hours but later it stopped.I started restarting the network-manager by typing the command :-

```
sudo systemctl restart network
```

It said,

```
Unit network.service not found
```

and when I typed the command :-

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

The output was this :-

```
mayur@mayur-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for mayur: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: b0:5a:da:9d:ff:2f
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=172.30.100.242 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c5000000-c5000fff memory:c5100000-c5103fff
  *-generic DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Illegal Vendor ID
       vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: wlp13s0f0
       version: ff
       serial: 00:e0:4c:81:92:8f
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.10.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3000000-c3003fff
```

What should I do?

Output :-

```
mayur@mayur-HP-Notebook:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
mayur@mayur-HP-Notebook:~$ dmesg | grep rtl
[   13.752830] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   13.752832] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   13.795239] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
[   13.800568] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[   13.800571] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   13.800576] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   13.815172] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   13.815514] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   14.235141] rtl8723be 0000:0d:00.0 wlp13s0: renamed from wlan0
[16343.485167] Modules linked in: ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp iptable_filter nf_nat_h323 nf_conntrack_h323 nf_nat_pptp nf_nat_proto_gre nf_conntrack_pptp nf_conntrack_proto_gre nf_nat_tftp nf_conntrack_tftp nf_nat_sip nf_conntrack_sip nf_nat_irc nf_conntrack_irc nf_nat_ftp nf_conntrack_ftp iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack libcrc32c ip_tables x_tables ccm rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper arc4 cryptd intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf rtl8723be(-) joydev btcoexist input_leds rtl8723_common serio_raw rtl_pci
[16343.485204]  rtlwifi mac80211 btusb btrtl intel_pch_thermal btbcm btintel snd_hda_codec_realtek cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_generic lpc_ich bluetooth snd_soc_rt298 snd_soc_ssm4567 snd_soc_rt286 mei_me snd_hda_intel snd_soc_rl6347a shpchp mei snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec processor_thermal_device snd_compress intel_soc_dts_iosf ac97_bus snd_hda_core snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq int3403_thermal snd_seq_device snd_timer snd int3402_thermal int340x_thermal_zone snd_soc_sst_acpi soundcore dw_dmac snd_soc_sst_match dw_dmac_core spi_pxa2xx_platform i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core 8250_dw int3406_thermal tpm_crb int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel hp_wireless acpi_pad mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea
[16343.485326]  rtl_pci_disconnect+0x193/0x1e3 [rtl_pci]
[16343.485345]  rtl8723be_driver_exit+0x10/0x6be [rtl8723be]
[16378.491054] rtl8723be 0000:0d:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[16378.491298] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
[16378.492553] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[16378.493271] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[16378.514839] rtl8723be 0000:0d:00.0 wlp13s0f0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep rtl`

Comment: edited the question @chill555

Comment: Have you selected the correct antenna? https://askubuntu.com/questions/991418/low-wi-fi-signal-in-hp-laptop-with-ubuntu-16-04/991515#991515

Comment: I had selected ant_sel=2

Comment: Is there any change if you try ant_sel=1?

Comment: I tried but the result was same. Same output came as I posted here

Comment: I also have the internet/wifi not working. Using Lubuntu on an iMac G4. What can I do to make it work? Can anyone help or direct me? Thanks.

Comment: Found out the command I used was not right. This site helped me, after the first command my wired internet started working: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restart-network-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-linux

Comment: The command that helped me was: sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service

Answer (score 1):

We see some interesting clues in *lshw*:

```
*-generic DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Illegal Vendor ID
       vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
```

And in *dmesg*:

```
[16343.485345]  rtl8723be_driver_exit+0x10/0x6be [rtl8723be]
[16378.491054] rtl8723be 0000:0d:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
```

The illegal vendor ID is sometimes observed with parts purchased overseas that are apparently cheap clones. It is sometimes also observed in parts that have failed electrically. In either case, I suggest that your laptop is in need of a replacement wireless card.

Comment: But in when I had windows 10 in my laptop,there was no issue regarding wireless card.It ran without any problem.But when I installed ubuntu 16.04 freshly,I had this problem.