# How to select antenna with Intel wifi driver?

Tags: wireless, 18.04, network-manager, iwlwifi

This question and answer
[Low Wi-Fi signal in HP laptop with Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991418/low-wi-fi-signal-in-hp-laptop-with-ubuntu-16-04) explains how to solve a wifi weak signal problem by selecting the antenna in the case of a Realtek network adapter. Is there any way to do the same with the Intel adapter with the iwlwifi driver?

Comment: Maybe also of interest of anyone coming to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014198/how-to-make-intel-wi-fi-signal-stronger-in-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-or-18-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Linux drivers have a setable parameter to prefer antenna 1 vs. antenna 2. Your driver, *iwlwifi*, does not. I suggest that you check to see that both antenna wires are firmly snapped in place.

[image]

In this example, they are identified as Main and Aux.