# Proper way to fix slow WiFi

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I have a laptop - *Jumper EZBOOK 3 PRO*.
It has the wireless adapter - *Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165*.
I've installed *Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS* and have a problem with super slow WiFi connection.
And there is no problem using *Windows 10*.

I found the fix - [to disable 802.11n](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029723/slow-wifi-since-updating-to-18-04/1037623?newreg=ac0e4c9477ee46a2820483b93b7c18df).
But this is not a good option, because I still will not have the maximum speed. I want to have 802.11n working fine.

So the question is - **Is there another solution?**
For example, [updating kernel](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063311) or somehow [installing proper driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1071565) or to use NDISwrapper.
**Can you suggest me what to do?**

P.S. I've tried to [fix driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1071565), but it wasn't successful. Also I've checked 802.11ac and it works fine.
P.S.S. I've booted *Manjaro* and have the same problem.

Comment: NDISwrapper is NOT the solution.

Comment: Did you try switching the antenna selected?  Search this site for antenna selection or google ubuntu antenna selection

Comment: @ubfan1 I'm not familiar with antenna selection, but seems I can't do it. https://askubuntu.com/a/1060790/887142

Comment: If you have only one antenna wire, try moving it to the other post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried to [fix the driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1071565/887142) again. 
But I didn't succeeded - WiFi speed remained the same.

So I [upgraded the kernel](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063311/887142) from 4.15 to 4.19 using [*ukuu*](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu).
It was easy and quick - and now WiFi works as expected.

By the way, the firmware is the same as on previous kernel - *iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode*.
I'm not the Pro Linux guy. So if sb wants to explain smth, I will gladly listen.