# Wifi and Bluetooth not working simultaneously

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth, wifi-direct

I dual-booted my laptop with ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10. In Ubuntu when I'm trying to use wifi and Bluetooth simultaneously they are interfering with each other. I'm unable to use the internet through wifi when connected to a Bluetooth headset. A quick google search showed me that they both use the 2.5GHz ISM band, which is why they are interfering. But in Windows 10 everything works fine. My laptop has a Realtek RTL8723BE network adapter which doesn't support the 5GHz band.

Solutions I have already tried

1. Turned off wifi and Bluetooth coexistence with the below command.

`sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"`

Source: https://techvorm.com/fix-wifi-not-working-slows-ubuntu-bluetooth-turned

2. Tried running this command

`echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0 auto_agg=0 swcrypto=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-options.conf > /dev/null`

Source: [wi-fi and bluetooth not working simultaneously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645009/wi-fi-and-bluetooth-not-working-simultaneously)

3. I tried to remove the `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` package using this

`sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

Source: https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/issues/143

4. Lastly I tried this

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723-ant-sel.confecho
```

Source: https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/issues/143

Here is the output of the `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:1724]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b719 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5a01 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Did you try changing the WiFi channel of your AP?

Comment: The question is (unusually) well written, I commend you for this.
I suggest you post sources you read for each of the alternatives you tried.

Comment: Is this an HP laptop?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I use mobile hotspot so I can't change channel.

Comment: @Jeremy31 No, this is an Asus laptop.

Comment: With an Asus, don't set the antenna as HP is the only manufacturer we know that needs it so far

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you have made a few driver parameter selections for *iwlwifi*, a wireless driver for Intel devices. You have none; yours is a Realtek.

While the parameter selections do no harm, they are needless and merely take up space. I suggest that you remove them.

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-options.conf
```

Second, I shall be very surprised if the device doesn’t support 5 gHz channels; let’s confirm:

```
sudo iwlist freq
```

Does your router support 5 gHz?

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

If so, I suggest that you rename the 5 gHz band in the administration pages of the router, something like redhu5 or some such and connect to it instead.

Next, you tried ant_sel=2 with no success. Please try ant_sel=1:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723-ant-sel.conf
```

Reboot and see if there is any improvement.

Finally, as has been suggested, try setting a fixed channel in your router, either 1, 6 or 11. After making any change, reboot the router. See if any of these brings improvement.

Comment: I'm sure that my device doesn't support 5GHz channels. I checked with `sudo iwlist freq`
I don't have a router I use mobile hotspot to connect to the internet and when I change mobile hotspot to 5gHz, my laptop doesn't detect any wifi connection.
I also tried ant_set=1 but no luck.

Comment: Can the mobile hotspot be set to a fixed channel?

Comment: I checked it's not possible.

Comment: I regret that I have no other suggestions. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You already used antenna selection.
But perhaps selecting a different antenna would help, see [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=208472) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060785/how-to-select-antenna-with-intel-wifi-driver).

One action that might help diagnosing the problem is trying to see what are the differences between Win 10 and Ubuntu.
See [this](https://superuser.com/a/1291946/245595) for antenna selection, and [this](https://superuser.com/a/1320583/245595) for *Bluetooth Collaboration*, and compare with Ubuntu.