# Bluetooth Adapter slowing Wifi Connection on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I have recently downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 on a computer I built, and I installed a bluetooth adapter in order to access the internet. However, upon connecting to my Asus BT400 bluetooth adapter, I have experienced a major reduction in my internet speed compared to my Windows 10 laptop. I have disabled bluetooth coexistence with Wifi, but my internet speeds are still incredibly slow.

Any ideas on how to improve these internet speeds?

Comment: Please clarify whether you're using Bluetooth as the internet connection -or- the problem occurs when connecting the Bluetooth dongle but you're still using the same WiFi connection? Is your "Windows 10 laptop" using the same connection. I understand you're a "confused individual" but your questions here must not be.

Comment: FYI, if you're actually using Bluetooth then you should know it is really slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try

1. [Changing the antenna](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=208472) used for wifi.
2. The channel used by the router (the method for this depends on the router).

**Notes**:

1. Why do you need "a bluetooth adapter in order to access the internet"?
2. So you: 1) had a wifi working at a reasonable speed, 2) added bluetooth and wifi speed slowed down, 3) disabled bluetooth and wifi is still slow? If not, what is the sequence you tested?

**Related**:

1. [Wifi and Bluetooth not working simultaneously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340177/wifi-and-bluetooth-not-working-simultaneously)
2. https://www.codejourney.net/2017/04/wifi-and-bluetooth-interference-diagnosing-and-fixing/

Comment: I am trying the bluetooth adapter instead of a wifi adapter in order to access the internet, since it is all that I have. I added the bluetooth adapter, and experienced a slowdown. It's the adapter slowing things down.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using the bluetooth adapter to access the internet, and experiencing slow speeds as a result, that's to be expected. Bluetooth is a slow protocol. Depending on the version, the max *theoretical* bandwidth (which you will never actually achieve) is

- Bluetooth 3.0 up to 24 Mbits/s (3 MB/s)
- Bluetooth 2.0 up to 3 Mbits/s
  (400 KB/s)
- Bluetooth 1.0 up to 700 Kbits/s (less than 100 KB/s)

Comment: OP isn't trying to connect to the internet with Bluetooth. OP is complaining about the reduced  WiFi speed when the Bluetooth is enabled.

Comment: That's what the previous answer assumed, but the OP didn't actually say this in the post. "I installed a bluetooth adapter in order to access the internet" sounds like they're using Bluetooth for a network connection because "it is all that I have".